# How to force Rails to emulate PUT/PATCH/DELETE with POST for remote links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's what I found in docs:

> However, most browsers don't support methods other than "GET" and "POST" when it comes to submitting forms.
>
> Rails works around this issue by emulating other methods over POST with a hidden input named "_method", which is set to reflect the desired method:

In my case it sends real PATCH/PUT/DELETE requests and it causes problems in some browsers. How do I make it behave as described in docs?

**UPD:** I checked once more: method emulation works fine for forms but doesn't for remote links

**UPD2:** The code. This creates a link I can click and see PATCH request in console and catch the result using `ajax:success` event

```
<%= link_to(toggle_some_bool_field_path(row), remote: true, method: :patch) do %>
    <span>smth</span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How do you know it sends real PATCH and others?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I see them in firebug. Also I had problems with some PATCH requests until switched to POST in routes.rb

Comment: I'm curious.  What browsers have problems with PATCH/PUT/DELETE?

Comment: @infused I had random problems with random Chrome installations returning ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. You can check my other question which didn't get any attention of the community

Comment: You should post the code you are using.  That's where the problem is likely to be - Chrome works totally fine with PATCH and friends.

Comment: @infused added some code but actually I don't see there's anything special in it. Chrome should work fine but not all of Chromes do, also even one Firefox (v.35 I think) didn't.